# Rails: errors.add displays HTML tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Today, i have started getting a strange issue on validations.

Here is the code.

```
self.errors.add("", 'Must confirm your current password to set a new one')
```

But i am getting HTML tags in output. Like the one below.

```
<div id="errorList" class="errorList"><div class="errorListInner"><h5>1 error prohibited saving your profile</h5><ul><li> Must confirm your current password to set a new one</li></ul></div></div>
```

CSS isn't getting applied, i think. I am working on rails 3.1.3 and ruby 1.9.2.

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with a simple fix.

Dont do anything with this in model. Just put "raw" in you view where these errors are being populated.

Like

```
<%= raw a_helper_function_for_errors %>
```